# Why does it take time for the reputation in the flair to get updated?

Tags: support, flair, caching

Whenever the reputation of an user is changed I can see that the reputation in one's flair is not updated along with it.

I noticed  that it is mentioned in the site that

> flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours

But why?

Comment: uh.. why is this being voted down..? i would be happy to correct if i had asked anything stupid..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Because caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Depending on where you put the image, the file could be requested *a lot of times*. Generating the image is a relatively expensive process (in terms of CPU time) so in order to avoid overloading the Stack Exchange servers, flair images are cached.

If you want people to check your current up-to-the-minute accurate reputation, then include a link to your profile so they can click on the image.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, but I've ask [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276091/new-reputation-not-calculated-for-only-the-black-flair) on Meta SE where you can see all my flairs but one of them is not up to date. Can you explain how these comes? PS read also the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it would be too expensive to do constant updates. Generating once a day and caching the result keeps the cost reasonable.