# Combined Flair Rep Not Updating After More Than 36 Hours

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, flair

I have read in this question : [Why does it take time for the reputation in the flair to get updated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280028/why-does-it-take-time-for-the-reputation-in-the-flair-to-get-updated)
that flair updates every 24 - 36 hours, which really doesn't matter to me at all. But it started to get weird. Checking my account constantly everyday, my rep has not changed nor has my badge count. After 2 days, I thought it was a minor glitch. Now, about 4 - 5 days/48 - 60 hours, my flair is ***still*** not updating. Why is this happening?

Comment: Your Stack Overflow flair image shows 467 reputation for me, which is accurate as the other +10 just came in half an hour ago. Are you sure you don't still have a cached version on your system? Try a hard refresh. (Addendum: your combined flair actually shows the correct 477 for me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did have an issue with outdated cache flair.  It should be resolve this point.