# Missing avatar from main site flair

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flair

When viewing [my site flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/5958455.png) for Stack Overflow, the avatar is missing (static images used throughout for demonstration purposes):

[image]

The missing avatar happens only to the default style.

> [image]

My Meta flair and Combined flair are also fine:

[image]

How can I get my main site flair working?

Comment: Can confirm that it is broken for me when viewing your "default" flair (mine works fine), so it's not just a geographical issue.

Comment: Likely there was just a connectivity fail last time it generated that image and it will fix itself once the cache expires. It shows with a profile picture when I load it.

Comment: @animuson Doesn't this all happen within Stack Overflow's datacenter? I supposed connectivity *there* would be much more reliable than the public Internet.

Comment: It has to download the image from Imgur in order to put it onto the flair image. We've no control over temporary outages at Imgur.

Comment: @animuson OK that makes sense. I'll check back after some time and see if things self-remediate.

Answer (score 4):

According to [animuson's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412507/missing-avatar-from-main-site-flair#comment875037_412507), Stack Overflow's flair generator has to fetch the avatar from Imgur which is out of SO's datacenter and control. As a result it's perfectly reasonable that it fails to retrieve the avatar occasionally. In this case just wait for some time for the cached flair to expire and (hopefully) a new one will be generated without problems.

[image]

The flair may be cached for [up to 36 hours](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280028/5958455) normally. My case was resolved after some 12 hours.

Comment: Weirdly, it is not resolved for me. The first flair shown in your question is still missing the avatar when I view it.

Comment: @CodyGray The first image is downloaded-then-uploaded so that future readers don't get confused seeing everything OK (unlike other flair-related bug reports). The link in the first line however points to the "dynamic image" and can be clicked.

Comment: Ooohhh. Your attempt at eliminating confusion has left me confused. :-)